# Adding an ACF CPT to an Woocomerce Product

Tags: woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

Scenario: I am currently building an Onlinestore for an Bookfactory, but we want to get more Focus on the Author - so unlike in the past each Author now gets an own page where each of his books should be reference to + on the productpage there should be an short preview of the Author.

We want to use ACF & Woocomerce for this

Already tried the Relationshipfunctions from ACF in combination with Woocommerce - but now i am kinda stuck since nothing works as i thought it would

Comment: There is no need to use ACF if its only for relationship. Wordpress already have user template. All products are connected to author (by default the one who creates the product) and can be changed so here is your relationship. "now i am kinda stuck since nothing works as i thought it would" give more details.

Comment: YES Wordpress has got user templates, but unfortunatly the user templates are offering to less options + they need to be real accounts as far as i know

Comment: You can add custom taxonomy to product and will do the same relationship. What do you mean by less options ?

Comment: i can add custom taxonomy true true
yeah we missing things like date of birth/death; links to social media....

Comment: Those are meta fields To better understand the wordpress as a system ill suggest to have a look in the documentation - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_term_meta/

Comment: Thanks a lot :P - Yes maybe it will help